# Install4j MAC OS X Auto-Update

Tags: macos, auto-update, install4j

I have followed these links to implement auto-update functionality for my windows installer and its working as expected.

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/concepts/autoUpdate.html

and

http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2010/12/beyond-installing.html

Is install4j auto-update functionality supported for Mac OS? If yes, Then what change do i need to make here? I have followed the same steps as described in above URL for Mac Installer and it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks !!

Comment: Yes, auto-update works on Mac OS X as well. What exactly does not work for you?

Comment: I configured the Mac installer settings for auto-update same way as that of windows. I am starting a java service after installation (SystemTray). This service was not invoked in Mac, nor did the auto-update part.

Comment: The auto-update cannot be invoked from a daemon on Mac OS X, it has to be a GUI launcher.

Comment: yes, my launcher is a GUI launcher

Comment: Instead of the automatic launcher integration you can try the integration wizard and add the code snippet to your code, then it is easier to see what is happening.